# Hyperlinks displaced on IE7

Tags: browser

Browse to a webpage with hyperlinks using  IE (I am using IE7) Once on the page, enlarge the fonts using ctl + mouse wheel. Now when  you try to hover over the hyperlinks, they are laterally displaced to the right. To click on the link, i have to move the mouse to the right till the cursor turns into a hand. 
Anyone has a comment on this??

---

[I was browsing the following page](http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2008/08/19/hyper-v-and-visual-studio-2008-sp1.aspx).

It is the 2nd hyperlink in the body of the article. (the link text is "here")

Comment: Can you attach the corresponding HTML and CSS please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 doesn't handle Zoom correctly, You can see this error on this page (I mean the page you're reading right now) if you zoom large enough, view the logout | about link at the top, hover over it, hover off to the right, back over.

Answer (score 0):

All of the links on that page are displaced to the right on my copy of IE7 (7.0.6001.18000) even before I enlarge or shrink the fonts.  Whereas other pages act normally.  (My test page was http://www.frito-lay.com/fl/flstore/cgi-bin/good_questions.htm).

It appears to be something specific to the page.